# what is the physical interpretation of poles and zeros of a mechanical system?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, applied-mechanics

what is the physical interpretation of poles and zeros of a mechanical system?
I'm asking things like the meaning if I have only 0 or only complex numbers. And about the number of the poles and zeros, it should be equal? What can I infer about the stability?

Comment: Do you mean you want to look at the poles and zeros of a mechanical system and make judgements about how it will act?  Or do you mean you want to map back from the poles (and possibly zeros) in a transfer function to the motors, gears, wheels, and whatnot in your mechanical system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The poles and zeros of a LTI plant or system in relation to their eigenvalues determine how quickly a system will stabilize or destabilize and if it oscillates.

When looking at these in the complex plane, the Re(a+ib) determine how quickly a system will exponentially stabilize or destabilize (the left vs right half plane) while the Im(a+ib) determine how the system oscillates. (High/low freq and amplitude)

The poles and zeros do not have to be equal, however imaginary systems always appear in pairs namely a+ib and a-ib.

A system is absolutely stable if all poles are at the left half plane =<0.

Other stability descriptions can be named depending on specific criteria such as conditional, marginal, or unstable or chaotic depending on where poles lie.

You can find a lot of infos on the web about this, such as t[his pdf from MIT.](https://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/PoleZero.pdf) (warning pdf)

Comment: A polish soccer team was flying to a match in England when the pilot decided to circle london so the passengers could see the town, He circled to the right and all the passengers crowded the windows on that side, and the plane crashed as a result of all the poles being in the right half of the plane. This is engineering humor, you may now laugh.